# How to code triple of real numbers to binary?

Tags: coding-theory, binary

Let's assume that we have a triple (4.56,-14.1,12767861).

We want to represent this as binary number.

How this is possible?

I apologize in advance if this is not the correct place to ask such question.

Comment: What is your model of a "binary number"?

Comment: Code each real number to binary separately. Then interleave the bits.

Comment: The textual representation of the number and comma are ASCII (or ISO-8859-1) characters which are essentially $7$-bit (or $8$-bit) integers. concatenate the bits will give you a single number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know already have at your disposal a binary representation/coding (of fixed finite length)(*) for real numbers (**), then you can simply represent the triple by appending the three single encodings.

If you are instead thinking of the standard binary notation, with potentially infinite length, then you could also get a single representation by interleaving bits. This would hardly be practical or useful, though. Also, this question would also apply for decimal representation.

(*) For example, [some IEEE 754 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Or also the ASCII encoding of the decimal digits (to some predetermined precision and bounds).

(**) Obviously, you cannot represent exactly all real numbers with a fixed-length format, a loss of precision (and possibility of overflow/underflow must be accepted).